# I want to create a program that finds the longest substring in alphabetical order using python using basics

Tags: python, python-3.x, edx

my code for finding longest substring in alphabetical order using python

what I mean by longest substring in alphabetical order? 
if the input was"asdefvbrrfqrstuvwxffvd" the output wil be "qrstuvwx"

```
#we well use the strings as arrays so don't be confused
s='abcbcd'
#give spaces which will be our deadlines
h=s+'    (many spaces)                                                                      '
#creat outputs
g=''
g2=''
#list of alphapets
abc='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

#create the location of x"the character the we examine"  and its limit 
limit=len(s)
#start from 1 becouse we substract one in the rest of the code
x=1
while (x<limit):
    #y is the curser that we will move the abc array on it
    y=0
    #putting our break condition first
    if ((h[x]==' ') or (h[x-1]==' ')):
        break
    for y in range(0,26):
        #for the second character x=1
        if ((h[x]==abc[y]) and (h[x-1]==abc[y-1]) and (x==1)):
            g=g+abc[y-1]+abc[y]

            x+=1
        #for the third to the last character x>1
        if ((h[x]==abc[y]) and (h[x-1]==abc[y-1]) and (x!=1)):
            g=g+abc[y]
            x+=1
        if (h[x]==' '):
            break
print ("Longest substring in alphabetical order is:" +g )
```

it doesn't end,as if it's in infinite loop
what should I do?
I am a beginner so I want some with for loops not functions from libraries
Thanks in advance

Comment: @natn2323 no, the line is `h=s+' (many spaces) '`

Comment: @Jonas for lines like that, I find it best to do something along the lines of: `A_SPACE = ' '` followed by `h = s + A_SPACE*74` (or however many spaces you have there). Edit - sorry just realized you're not the asker

Comment: Is there a requirement for using `h`, or is that something you wanted to do?

Comment: @natn2323 No, I just used it to have a spot where I can call it 'end'
I am still  a beginner, but I found it easier to break it using spaces than numbers since s could vary as an input.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'abcbcdiawuhdawpdijsamksndaadhlmwmdnaowdihasoooandalw'
longest = ''
current = ''
for idx, item in enumerate(s):
    if idx == 0 or item > s[idx-1]:
        current = current + item
    if idx > 0 and item <= s[idx-1]:
        current = ''
    if len(current)>len(longest):
        longest = current
print(longest)
```

Output:

```
dhlmw
```

For your understanding `'b'>'a'` is `True`, `'a'>'b'` is `False` etc

Edit:

For longest consecutive substring:

```
s = 'asdefvbrrfqrstuvwxffvd'
abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
longest = ''
current = ''
for idx, item in enumerate(s):
    if idx == 0 or abc.index(item) - abc.index(s[idx-1]) == 1:
        current = current + item
    else:
        current = item
    if len(current)>len(longest):
        longest = current
print(longest)
```

Output:

```
qrstuvwx
```

Comment: @natn2323 No? In my world it is -> abc**d**efg**h**ijk**lm**nopqrstuv**w**xyz

Comment: @jonas but it's not really an alphabetical order since the letter aren't next to each other

Comment: @kuro-san then it that case, what you want is the longest, consecutive alphabetical substring.You should mention this in your post. Also, that's why it's good to have an example output.

Comment: @kuro-san the answer should be `qrstuvwx` and not `rstuvwx`

Comment: @Jonas This does not produce the intended results. Edit it

Comment: @Onyambu oops, forgot the first letter. edited again

Answer (score 0):

To avoid infinite loop add `x += 1` in the very end of your while-loop. As a result your code works but works wrong in general case.

The reason why it works wrong is that you use only one variable `g` to store the result. Use at least two variables to compare previous found substring and new found substring or use list to remember all substrings and then choose the longest one.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sub_strings(string):
    substring = ''
    string +='\n'
    i = 0
    string_dict ={}
    while i < len(string)-1:
        substring += string[i]
        if ord(substring[-1])+1 != ord(string[i+1]):
            string_dict[substring] = len(substring)
            substring = ''
        i+=1
    return string_dict   

 s='abcbcd'

 sub_strings(s)
  {'abc': 3, 'bcd': 3}
```

To find the longest you can do`max(sub_strings(s))`

So here which one do you want to be taken as the longest??. Now that is a problem you would need to solve

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the string and keep comparing to the last character and append to the potentially longest string if the current character is greater than the last character by one ordinal number:

```
def longest_substring(s):
    last = None
    current = longest = ''
    for c in s:
        if not last or ord(c) - ord(last) == 1:
            current += c
        else:
            if len(current) > len(longest):
                longest = current
            current = c
        last = c
    if len(current) > len(longest):
        longest = current
    return longest
```

so that:

```
print(longest_substring('asdefvbrrfqrstuvwxffvd'))
```

would output:

```
qrstuvwx
```

Comment: It's pretty common to name the primary string `s` and the current character `c` so I did not give these two variable longer names.

Comment: I meant that you posted the same answer as me half an hour later, even calling the two strings current and longest :D

Comment: Huh? I didn't even look at anyone else's answer. `current` and `longest` are very common variable names in the context of this question. Our logics actually differ by a whole lot so what makes you think it's the "same answer"?